# Eclipse references to code under #ifdef

Tags: eclipse

I am using Eclipse references (Ctrl+shift+G). I noticed that Eclipse misses references if they are under #ifdef.  Is there a way to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily define the preprocessor symbol in the project properties. For example, for:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    log("Hello")
#endif
```

Go to the project properties:

```
C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols > Symbols.
```

Set the "DEBUG" symbol there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a way to overcome this issue totally and not by defining all existing symbols?

Comment: There is no workaround to parse the "inactive" code. Eclipse C++ parser follows exactly the source code.